# Using collection as property in class (Argument not optional)

Tags: vba, excel, class, collections

I'm trying to use a collection of dates as a class property, and having trouble with it. Essentially, I want to store multiple `vacLocation` in `emp_vacDates`, and have it feeding into `employee.Vaca`.

I have no problem working with `Employee.Name`

The error I get is

> Compile error: Argument not optional

at the `Vaca` Let statement

My code is:

```
Sub Vacation()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rowNum As Long: rowNum = 5
    Dim colNum As Long: colNum = 4
    Dim onePersonLoop As Range
    Dim nameLocation As Range
    Dim vacLocation As Range
    Dim emp_vacDates As Collection
    Dim emps As Collection
    Dim employee As EmployeeClass

    For i = 2 To 2
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i)

            Set onePersonLoop = .Cells(rowNum, colNum).Offset(-1).End(xlToRight).Offset(, -2)
            Set emps = New Collection
            For rowNum = 5 To 5

                Set nameLocation = .Cells(rowNum, colNum).Offset(-1, -1).EntireRow.Cells(1, 2)
                Set employee = New EmployeeClass
                employee.Name = nameLocation.Value
                Set emp_vacDates = New Collection

                For colNum = 4 To 6

                    Set vacLocation = .Cells(rowNum, colNum).Offset(-3)
                    If .Cells(rowNum, colNum) = "v" Or .Cells(rowNum, colNum) = "V" Then
                        emp_vacDates.Add vacLocation.Value
                    End If
                Next colNum

                employee.Vaca = emp_vacDates
                emps.Add employee

                Debug.Print employee.Name
                Debug.Print employee.Vaca

            Next rowNum

        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

I have my EmployeeClass class module set up like this

```
Option Explicit

Dim vName As String
Dim vVaca As Collection

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = vName
End Property

Public Property Let Name(nme As String)
    vName = nme
End Property

Public Property Get Vaca() As Collection
    Vaca = vVaca
End Property

Public Property Let Vaca(vcl As Collection)
    vVaca = vcl
End Property
```

Comment: Just a question: Why do you use a loop `For rowNum = 5 To 5` and `For i = 2 To 2` that doesn't loop? This is a pretty useless loop. I hope this is only a test case?

Comment: Yea, test case. Didn't want to loop the whole thing while I figure this out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collections should be `Set`. 
Like this:

```
Public Property Get Vaca() As Collection
    Set Vaca = vVaca
End Property

Public Property Let Vaca(vcl As Collection)
    Set vVaca = vcl
End Property
```

Furthermore, you cannot just debug.print a collection like this:

`Debug.Print employee.Vaca`

Try to do something else there, e.g.:

```
Debug.Print employee.Vaca.Item(1)
```

Or write a function, checking whether there is an item in the collection and printing `0` if there is no item. Something like this:

```
Public Function VacaToString(Optional index = 1) As String

    If Vaca.Count = 0 Then
        VacaToString = 0
    Else
        VacaToString = Vaca(index)
    End If

End Function
```

Then you can debug.print it like this:

```
Debug.Print employee.VacaToString
```

Answer (score 2):

`vVaca` and `vcl` are both of type `Collection` which is an object.
Objects have to use `set`

```
Public Property Get Vaca() As Collection
    Set Vaca = vVaca
End Property

Public Property Let Vaca(vcl As Collection)
    Set vVaca = vcl
End Property
```